# Memory Mapped File vbVerticalTab and vbNullChars appear in result

Tags: vb.net, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to use a Memory Mapped File (MMF) to store and transfer data between applications.

I've managed to create a MMF and 'kind of' read it.

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        createMMF()
        readMMF()
    End Sub

    Sub createMMF()
        Dim mmf As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 5)
        Dim stream As MemoryMappedViewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream()

        Dim writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(stream)
        writer.Write("hello there")
    End Sub
    Sub readMMF()

        Dim mmf As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap")
        Dim stream As MemoryMappedViewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream()

        Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
        Dim text = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

        Debug.Print(text)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Some questions:

1) In the CreateNew call I specify "5" as the size, and yet when I changed the .write call from "hello" to "hello there" it made no difference.

2) When I read my stream in the receiving function the string is there, but it contains a strange character at the beginning (decoded as vbVerticalTab in the debugger context) and lots of vbNullChars subsequently.

[image]

I'd like to be able to pass strings of say 10Kb between the processes and accurately get a string without the odd character at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: You are writing with the `BinaryWriter` that [writes additional information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter.write?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_BinaryWriter_Write_System_String_) such as the string length. You are then reading it with `StreamReader` that expects raw text without any metadata. Use a matching pair of a writer and a reader, and specify encoding explicitly.

Comment: BinaryWriter encodes the string, you must use BinaryReader to read it back.  The "strange character" is a byte that encodes the string length.  The null chars appear because you read too much.

Answer (score 1):

Okay thanks to the comments I've been able to get this working.  This is code for using a BinaryWriter/Reader.

```
   Sub createMMF()
        Dim mmf As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 11)
        Dim stream As MemoryMappedViewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream()

        Dim writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(stream)
        writer.Write("hello there")

    End Sub
    Sub readMMF()

        Dim mmf As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap")
        Dim stream As MemoryMappedViewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream()

        Dim binaryReader = New BinaryReader(stream)
        Dim length = binaryReader.Read()  'gives 11, length of "hello there" string.
        Dim text = binaryReader.ReadChars(length)

        Debug.Print(text)

    End Sub
```

Additionally I tested using the StreamReader/Writer pair instead.   I had to use a .flush() call in the writer and the ReadToEnd method still had a lot of null characters padding out.

```
 Sub createMMF()
        Dim mmf As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 11)
        Dim stream As MemoryMappedViewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream()

        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(stream)
        writer.Write("hello there")
        writer.Flush()

    End Sub
    Sub readMMF()

        Dim mmf As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap")
        Dim stream As MemoryMappedViewStream = mmf.CreateViewStream()

        Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
        Dim text = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        Debug.Print(text)

    End Sub
```

Inspecting the result you can see the vbNull chars.

[image]

One thing that made no difference in my testing is the Capacity parameter of the .CreateNew method.  Even if you put "1" in the string length in both examples are not affected.   From my reading of the docs this byte value should be set to reserve memory sufficient for the task.